# java adb pull file while running

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

I'd like to pull a file from the running android avd while running and to do that do:

```
String[] cmd ={ "adb pull /sdcard/dataFolder/dataFile /path/folder/"};
try{
     Process pr = run.exec(cmd);
     pr.waitFor();
     System.out.println("cmd execution done");
     pr.destroy();
} catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("IOException");
     e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     System.out.println("InterruptedException");
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It prints "cmd execution done" but not file is pulled into the local folder. Using the same command from terminal it works. Where am I wrong?

Comment: use absolute path of adb

Comment: including absolute path to adb executable file throws IOException. Not including it (having the executable file in the path) it prints "cmd execution done" but do nothing.

Comment: what is the `stdout` when your `cmd execution done`

Comment: now, i modified the cmd to: 
File dir = new File("adb absolute path"); String[] adbShell = { "adb", "shell", "mkdir", "/sdcard/createdFolder" }; Process pr = run.exec(adbShell,null, dir); but the stdOut says: Environment null. What i should put instead of null in the Environment String[]?

Comment: always getting IOException running command, if i also try with: String []cmd={"/bin/bash","mkdir.sh"}; Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,dir); where dir is the path to mkdir.sh file. any ideas?

Comment: I found the problem: i'm running android test in virtual device so my environment is the virtual device and i cannot execute shell commands. Any solutions?